# yandex-tank Phantom I/O engine not found

Tags: яндекс-танк

Ubuntu 22.04

Python 3.10

yandex-tank установлен был при помощи *pip3 install yandextank*

У меня есть такой вот конфиг, например

`cat load.yaml`

```
phantom:
  address: "mysite.ru:443"
  ssl: true
  headers:
    - "[accept: */*]"
    - "[user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    - "[Host: mysite.ru]"
  uris:
    - "/some_uri"
  load_profile:
    schedule: "line(500, 3500, 1m) const(3500, 5m)"
    load_type: rps
  instances: 10
console:
  enabled: true
telegraf:
  enabled: false
```

Когда я стартую *yandex-tank -c load.yaml* получаю следующую ошибку

```
09:11:20 [ERROR] Exception occurred:
<class 'OSError'>: Phantom I/O engine not found. More information: http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
  File "/home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yandextank/core/tankworker.py", line 72, in run
    self.core.plugins_prepare_test()

  File "/home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 279, in plugins_prepare_test
    plugin.prepare_test()

  File "/home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/plugin.py", line 102, in prepare_test
    raise OSError("Phantom I/O engine not found. More information: {doc_url}".format(
```

У  меня есть предположения что проблемы где-то переменной  `phantom_path` лобо где-то в локальных путях

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена откатом Ubuntu на `20.04 (focal)`
так как для `22.04 (Jammy)` у Яндекса в репах на данный момент, согласно иструкции по запуску танка https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html нет `phantom` и `phantom-ssl`